# Event handler not getting detected inside $(document).ready()

Tags: jquery

I have

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    createSearch();
    $('#search').bind('click', function(){
         if($(this).val()=='Search'){
             $(this).val('');
         }
   });
});

function createSearch(){
    $('#mainDiv').prepend('<input type="text" id="search" />');
}
```

However, the search `click` event is not getting detected.

Comment: [It works](http://jsfiddle.net/qdJ6b/).

Comment: Working properly as per above fiddle ,what else you want?

Comment: I'd recommend you replace your bind with [on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/) going forward if you have access to the latest version of jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a better approach like the one below. Find the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/EmaZ6/)

```
$('<input />',{
    type:'text',
    val:'Search',  // Just to set the value to 'Search' initially, you can remove it if not needed
    id:'search',
    click:function(){
        if($(this).val()=='Search')
            $(this).val('');
    }
}).prependTo('#mainDiv');
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you forget to set the value in the input?

```
function createSearch(){
    $('#mainDiv').prepend('<input type="text" id="search" value="Search" />');
}
```

See it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/5QeRa/)

Comment: That's it. Value was missing

Comment: @user544079 Why don't you use `placeholder` attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Add `value="Search"` in your input `type="text"` declaration.

Instead of all this javascript. you can use `placeholder = "Search"` in your text box declaration.